# For realm database for iOS swift app dev, what's the ideal way to structure a Class with a member variable array of another class?

Tags: ios, swift, database, architecture, realm

Think of Slack, where there are channels and each channel has posts. Say I have a Channel class and a Post class, where the Channel has an array of posts. Right now I give each post a string variable 'channel', so that when querying the DB I can pick out posts for a specific channel. This means that every time the user enters a channel I have to query every post in existence to see whether its intended for this specific channel. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Hi Kishan! Please edit your question and add your existing code. This will help us provide the best answer for you!

Comment: Have you read Realm's documentation on [to-many relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships)?

Answer (score 0):

While using some sort of foreign key like that might work in relational databases, there's a far easier way to link objects in Realm.

Like @bdash mentioned, Realm has a to-many object relationship feature, where a parent object can store references to multiple children.

```
class Post: Object {
    dynamic var message = ""
    let channel = LinkingObjects(fromType: Channel.self, property: "posts").first?
}

class Channel: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let posts = List<Post>()
}
```

You can also use the `LinkingObjects` object to let posts know which channel they belong to.

For more information, definitely please check out the [to-many relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships) section of the Realm documentation.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries! Feel free to accept this answer if that's all you needed. :)